# How to create a Kubernetes cron job that delete secrets older then "x" days age and ignore the last 2 versions

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

I would like to create a `kubectl` cron job that auto delete secrets older than "x" days age, except the latest 2 versions. The Apps in the cluster use these secrets for config, but they get created with every deploy and needs clean up after the fact.

Comment: Add samples of your secret output and explain what defines **latest 2 version**?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the

```
kubectl delete secret $(kubectl get secret | awk 'match($5,/[0-9]+d/) {print $1}')
```

You can parse the JSON like you can use the **seconds** (update 86400) as per need of **xdays** and write other conditions of the versions.

However, I don't think you can maintain versions with k8s secret, if you are using any `external secret` you can parse the version in JSON by modifying the command.

`kubectl get externalsecret ....`

Use **jq** command line to parse the JSON:

```
kubectl get secrets -o json | jq -r "[.items[] | {name: .metadata.name, startTime: .metadata.creationTimestamp | fromdate } | select(.startTime < (now | . - 86400))]" | jq -r ".[].name"
```

**Extra** :

If you don't want to use the kubectl you can use the Python or other language with client library and manage the secret and run that Docker image into **k8s** cronjob

Client libraries: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/